# Why does find -exec only accept {} in some positions?

Tags: command-line, find

The following command is working fine:

```bsh
find . -iname \*.7z -exec ls {} -al \;
```

But while I change `\;` to `\+` , That is:

```bsh
find . -iname \*.7z -exec ls {} -al \+
```

I got error report:

```
missing argument to `-exec'
```

I discover when I change `{}`'s position:

```bsh
find . -iname \*.7z -exec ls -al {} \+
```

The above command can work fine.

I feel confused about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The `+` form of `-exec` always places arguments at the end of the command you give.** Therefore, `{}`, which represents the arguments, must immediately precede `+`. This is dissimilar to the `;` form of `-exec`, which runs one command per file found and uses the filename wherever `{}` appears.

So that's your answer... but it does raise the additional question of why *that* limitation is in place in the first place, which is a bit murkier.

**With `+`, the `-exec` action runs your command as few times as possible, passing as many filenames as it can in place of `{}`.** Especially if there might be many files found, this form of `-exec` is only suitable for use with commands that behave the same--or at least in a way consistent with what you want--when the filenames are split across multiple invocations of the command, as they do when all the filenames appear in a single invocation.

Commands that accept a variable number of filename arguments in a single invocation, to produce the same effect as if the command were executed once for each filename, often accept them as trailing arguments. There are, of course, exceptions like `cp` and `mv` with directory targets (though you can pass `-t dir` to make those work with `+`). This is also somewhat easier to reason about, in that when you write `ls -l` followed by filenames, it feels like `ls -l` is "the command" you're running to operate on those named files, but when you write `ls`, followed by filenames, followed by `-l`, it doesn't quite feel that way.

**As for what to do about it, your approach of simply putting options like `-l` before the `{}` is good.** This has additional advantages: though less common on GNU/Linux systems like Ubuntu than on some other Unix-like operating systems, some commands don't accept options after a non-option argument has appeared. (See [getopt(3)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man3/getopt.3.html) for details.)

*Since you're running `ls`, you might consider using `find`'s `-ls` action instead of `-exec`. Note also that you don't need to quote `+`, since unlike `;`, shells don't treat the `+` character specially.*

Comment: This is very good and detailed answer! Thanks!

Comment: Note however that `find -ls` equals `find -exec ls -dils {} +`, not `find -exec ls -al {} +`. From `man find`: “list current file in ls -dils format”